# How to read a excel file using perl?

Tags: perl

How to read excel file in Perl CGI?

```
my $book = ReadData('$lBASEPATH/macro/$gProj/TCO_Excel_Export/TCO_Data_201931316467.xlsx');   

say 'A1: ' . $book->[1]{A1}; 

print $book;
```

Comment: What module are you using? How does your code fail?

Answer (score 3):

Enclose the path to the `.xlsx` file using double quotes inside ReadData function.

```perl
my $book = ReadData("$lBASEPATH/macro/$gProj/TCO_Excel_Export/TCO_Data_201931316467.xlsx");  

say 'A1: ' . $book->[1]{A1}; 

print $book;
```

It is not possible to do interpolation with single quotes.